# How can I send email through ZOHO api using PHP?

Tags: php, rest, api, email, zoho

I've followed [this doc](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/post-send-an-email.html) and here is my code:

```
$url = "https://mail.zoho.com/api/accounts/662704xxx/messages";
$param = [  "fromAddress"=> "myemail@mydomain.com",
            "toAddress"=> "somewhere@gmail.com",
            "ccAddress"=> "",
            "bccAddress"=> "",
            "subject"=> "Email - Always and Forever",
            "content"=> "Email can never be dead ..."];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($param));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
die;
```

And the response is:

```
{"data":{"errorCode":"INVALID_TICKET","moreInfo":"Invalid ticket"},"status":{"code":400,"description":"Invalid Input"}}
```

And the response means: *(according to [this](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/response-codes.html))*

> BAD REQUEST - The input passed in the Request API is invalid or incorrect. The requestor has to change the input parameters and send the Request again.

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Use PHPMailer for email sending.

Comment: @Devrajverma I don't have SMTP server installed on my server.

Comment: Maybe remove `ccAddress` and `bccAddress` if they are null and see if you can get a success.. Looks like everything else is fine but I feel like zoho is breaking because those 2 inputs are null and therefore, invalid

Comment: You likely need to add a `Content-Type: application/json` header telling the receiver that you actually are sending JSON in the request body ... by passing a string to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, it defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @CBroe I added `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));`, but sadly the result is still the same.

Comment: @MartinAJ, did you authenticate before trying to send the email? Also, you don't need a SMTP server on your server to use PHPMailer. I send all my email through Zoho using PHPMailer in a server without any mailing servers.

Comment: @ishegg well no, I didn't do anything about authentication. Can you please paste your code (sending email through Zoho using PHPMailer ) in here (or a gist on github) for me?

Comment: @MartinAJ try [this](https://gist.github.com/ishegg/fb67dc4d78ca9805b1381742dd93f577).

Comment: @ishegg Thank you buddy .. but sadly it throws `Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: data not accepted. in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:1757`

Comment: Set `$phpMailer->SMTPDebug = true;` to see further information.

Comment: @ishegg Oh great .. I did it .. thank you so much. If you add your code as an answer, I will accept it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @MartinAJ I submitted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to send mail with Zoho through its API, you need to first authenticate, as seen on [the APIDocs](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/post-send-an-email.html):

> Note: You can use the API [here](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/get-user-account-details.html) to retrieve the accountid for the currently authenitcated user.

That said, and refering to your comment, you don't need an SMTP server installed on your server to be able to send mail with PHPMailer:

> Integrated SMTP support - send without a local mail server

[Source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#class-features)

Zoho requires you to use TLS and the 587 port, so you can set up your connection like this:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$phpMailer = new PHPMailer(true);
$phpMailer->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$phpMailer->isSMTP();
$phpMailer->Host = "smtp.zoho.com";
$phpMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpMailer->Username = "your-user";
$phpMailer->Password = "your-password";
$phpMailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // or PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS
$phpMailer->Port = 587;
$phpMailer->isHTML(true);
$phpMailer->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$phpMailer->setFrom("mail-user", "mail-name");

$phpMailer->addAddress("mail-to");
$phpMailer->Subject = "subject";
$phpMailer->Body = "mail-body";
$phpMailer->send();
```

Comment: Just one question about PHPMailer. Should always `Username` and the first argument of `setFrom()` function be the same?

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't *have* to be the same, though having it be different will greatly increase the chances of it being flagged as spam, specially if the `from` mail is on another domain. For example, I think Google outright denies the mail being sent if those two are different.

Answer (score 1):

In my case everything I found on Google didn't make it work. It took me 3 days. And in the end it's simply like this and it magically works. Hope can help someone like me. What you need to do is remove the line below:

[image]

Comment: This fixed my issue, I ended up going over the configuration and settings a bunch of times.  Migrating from Godaddy, the isSMTP() flag is required, but this will cause Zoho to fail.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debug this solved my problem on my codeigniter php project using phpmailer,  ;
//$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
just delete this line. I should mention that zoho also blocked free acounts to use smtp.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional information. for example there is no ``$config['protocol'] = 'smtp'`` in op.